# Change the background color of a row on selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am new to Google Apps Script. I need advice.

I would need to create a script that changes the color of the row above which the cursor is hovering. If this isn't possible, it would be enough for me to change the background color of the entire row after clicking on any cell in that row. Is something like this possible?

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: It is not possible.  Closest possibility is to click on the cell and use onSelectionChange()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do with this problem is click on the first cell in the row you want to change and set up a `onSelectionChange(e)` function.

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) 
{
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let selection = sheet.getActiveRange();
  sheet.getRange(selection.getRowIndex(), 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0);
}
```

This code will highlight the line of the active cell when it is run.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. However, I don't know how to make it start automatically onOpen starts the onSelectionChange function ... To go in a loop and mark the whole row every time I click on another cell and at the same time erase the color of the previous row. But I'm probably speculating too much :D